# Reversing a linked list in Java without changing the original

Tags: java, linked-list, pass-by-reference

I am trying to reverse a linked list which works, but when I try to print the original, it fails (only prints the head). My question is, why would reversing affect the original. Below is my code. LinkedList is my own class, so is Node. Before reversing, if I try to print my list, that works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList list;
    ...
    Node head = list.getHead();
    Node rev = reverse(head);
    Node temp = rev;
    while (temp != null) {
        System.out.println(temp);
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    temp = head;
    while (temp != null) {
        System.out.println(temp);
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}

private static reverse(Node head) {
     // Reversing the linked list
}
```

EDIT::
This seems to be a Java thing. Java passes an object by reference. When I pass head as a parameter, it's passed by reference and any change made to it is reflected in the calling function.
Doing Node h = head and then passing h as a parameter won't work either since h will be the same object as head.
The only option I can think of is to create a new object, copy the linked list over and pass that as a parameter.

My question becomes, is there a better solution?

Comment: Do you mean something like Node h = head; reverse(h)

Comment: You have to call `new Node()` in order to get a separate object.

Comment: @4castle so, if I do Node t = new Node() and then t = head, that still doesn't work. I'm assuming I have to do t = head, since that's what I'm trying to reverse?

Comment: You have to make a deep copy of the objects. Not just a shallow copy of the references to the objects. The only way to make a deep copy is to instantiate a new object, giving it the same values for all its fields.

Comment: You can do something simple like, create a vector of the data item type, iterate through your original list, adding the data item to the vector. Then create a new list, iterate over the vector backwards from the end to the start, and add new Nodes into your new List, using the data item from the vector.  If your Node type is already bi directional (has both next and previous pointers) then you can go all the way to the end of it and then go backwards from there, adding copies into your new list without using the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand it, picture your list looks like this

```
list (list.head =a) --> a (a.next=b) --> b (b.next= c) -> c (c.next = null)
```

If you get the head, then you are getting object 'a'.
Then you are modifying object 'a'.
So you can see you are editing the list by doing this.

What you need to do is:
  Get the head 
  Create a copy
  Reverse the copy
  Get the next item
  Copy it
  Reverse it
  Join it to the last
  And so on

Since you are using your own classes not java collections classes, the easiest way is for you to make sure that reverseNode() only edits a copy of the one you pass it, and returns the copy.
First make sure your Node class has a constructor that copies another Node, then do something like this:

```
private static Node reverse(Node original) 
{
  Node retval = new Node(original);
  // or you could use clone () as Bhavik suggested, if your Node class implements it
  // modify retval 
  // I haven't shown code to reverse it as I assume you already have that and you didnt specify if it was a bidirectional list or just one direction.

  return retval;
}
```

Or you might add a static method in your Node class that constructs a new node that is reversed:

```
static Node createReverse(Node n) 
{
    return new Node(n.data,n.next,n.prior);
}
```

Or a non static method of the node class which returns a reversed copy of itself;

```
Node createReverse()
{
   return new Node(this.data,this.next,this.prior);
}
```

But you should consider this can get very ugly because your copies will still have pointers pointing into the existing list!

A better technique might be to create a new empty list, and then start from the end of your original, make a copy, and add it to the start of your new list.

You can use recursion to do this but might easily run out of memory.

But rather than do this manually, you might look at the java.util packages and switch to using one of their LinkedList and list item types. These classes have already solved all the problems with doing this stuff.

Then you could (if you need to keep the original list unmodified):
  - Make a copy of your entire list.
  - reverse the copy as below

If you don't care about keeping the original, then just use this method(below) on your list, no need then to make a copy.

From java.util.Collections:

```
Collections.reverse(List a_list);
```

The Collections class will choose an efficient way to reverse the list, depending on whether it is bidirectional, single directional, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Chunko's answer is right in that you should be creating copies of your Nodes instead of just passing references to them.
However, I think you might be overthinking this:

```
LinkedList reversedList = new LinkedList();
for (int i = originalList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedList.add(list.get(i));
}
```

Java's `LinkedList` doesn't have a `getHead()` method, so I guess you're using some homework-related custom implementation of a linked list. Still, your implementation should have an `add()` method that appends a new `Node` to the list, as well as a `get(int)` method that returns the item in a given position.
You can use those methods to create a new list and populate it with the original list's items in reversed order.

Comment: this solution is nice and simple but is probably O(nlogn) or similar unless the linked list implementation was backed by an array which I doubt as it's a custom one. hence why i suggested he skip forward through to the end copying them into an array/vector as he goes (could even preallocate it to the correct size), then it should be O(n) at the expense of temporarily more mem usage. But since it's his own class, he could also just make it bidirectional and add a getTail() method to go with the getHead() method, and then he can jump straight to the end and walk backwards with no further expense